# get_class_vars() not showing a variable, but property_exists() run on the same class returns true

Tags: php, class, object

I'm studying PHP, and I've started playing with classes--below is possibly the most basic object ever, lol.

```
<?php

    class Person {

        var $first_name;
        var $last_name;

        var $arm_count = 2;
        var $leg_count = 2;

        function say_hello() {
            echo "Hello from inside the class " . get_class($this) .".<br />";
        }
        function full_name() {
            return $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;
        }
    }

    $person = new Person();

    echo $person->arm_count . "<br />";

    $person->first_name = 'Lucy';
    $person->last_name = 'Ricardo';

    echo $person->full_name() . "<br />";

    $vars = get_class_vars('Person');
    foreach($vars as $var => $value) {
        echo "{$var}: {$value}<br />";
    }

    echo property_exists("person","first_name") ? 'true' : 'false';

?>
```

Then the above runs, it is supposed to output a bit of data.  In the lesson (a video training series by [Kevin Skoglund](http://twitter.com/#!/kskoglund), "[PHP: Beyond the Basics](http://www.lynda.com/home/displaycourse.aspx?lpk2=653)",) Kevin's screen looks correct (he's using 5.2.6.)

I'm on 5.3 on my WAMP installation, and my "first_name" attribute of the class Person is not being spit out by the loop... yet the `echo property_exists("person","first_name") ? 'true' : 'false';` returns true.

Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`property_exists` will return true if the property exists, no matter what the scope of the property and the caller are.

`get_class_vars` will return all properties accessible from the current scope, along with **their static values, or default values (for properties that are not declared static)**. However, it will not return properties that are not declared in the class body, nor will it accept an object argument.

Note that `property_exists` will also return false if a property that is not declared in the class body (i.e.: object context) is queried using the class name.

Per example:

```
class Foo {
    public $foo;
    private $bar;

    public function test() {
        var_dump(get_class_vars(__CLASS__));
    }
}

$obj = new Foo;
$obj->baz = 'hello';
property_exists($obj, 'bar');            // true
property_exists($obj, 'baz');            // true
property_exists(get_class($obj), 'baz'); // false

get_class_vars(get_class($obj));         // you get "foo" only
$obj->test();                            // you get "foo" and "bar", not "baz"
```

Comment: @netcoder - Ah, I see--so for what reason is my `var $first_name` not being declared as public? I understand the difference between the two, but not why I've encountered the difference...

Comment: @Julian: It is declared public. But it returns the default value, which is `null` (i.e.: nothing when you print it you).

Comment: @Julian: You probably should declared it `public` instead of `var` too. :)

Comment: @netcoder - I know it will return `null`, but let me rephrase the question: Why does every other variable (including `last_name`, which is also `null`) show up in the `foreach` loop's output? Adding `public` to `first_name` changed nothing... it still doesn't get spit out of the loop!

Comment: @Julian: .What if you `var_dump` the array instead? Or it could be a bug. What PHP version is that (specifically)?

Comment: @netcode - I'm running 5.3.0 on my WAMP installation--but the instructor uses 5.2.6 and there are no problems when he runs the exact same code. Running `var_dump` does indeed show the "hidden" first_name attribute.

Comment: @Julian: I had a lot of weird problems with 5.3.0. Most were fixed in 5.3.1. PHP 5.3.0 had big changes to the OO system and the parser, so it's not that surprising it has bugs. I suggest you to upgrade (latest is 5.3.5)  and try it with a newer version. I can't find anything on bugs.php.net or the changelog regarding that specific issue though...

Comment: @Julian: Actually, I tested it in 5.3.0 and 5.3.1 (on Linux), and it works as expected. Are you running it on Windows?

Comment: @netcode -- Yeah it's Windows. I'll go ahead and mark this as the accepted answer though... it was quite insightful. I'll trust that my knowledge is correct, and that this is an oddity (the instructor's code is identical and runs fine!)

Comment: @Julian: Unfortunately, I don't have any Windows machines, so I can't test it. But like I said, you really should upgrade to at least 5.3.1. It fixes a lot of issues.

Answer (score 1):

get_class_vars() returns only public access variables, while property_exists() checks for public, protected and private ones.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-class-vars.php 
vs. 
http://php.net/manual/de/function.property-exists.php